# JSF Backing bean not called via h:commandButton, page refreshes only

Tags: jsf, cdi, weld

I have a login page where on button submit I expect the backing bean method to be called. `@PostConstruct` method is called upon clicking the submit button, but the method in the backing bean (login method) is not called. No error messages are displayed, and there are no errors in the logs.

Here is my login.xhtml page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Login</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <p />
    <h:form id="login" prependId="false">
        <h:messages globalOnly="true" />
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username" />
        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="username" />
        <br />
        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{user.password}" required="true" />
        <h:message for="password" />
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Sign in" actionListener="#{user.login}" action="#{user.login}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And here is my backing bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@Named(value = "user")
public class UserController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String originalURL;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        originalURL = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

        if (originalURL != null) {
            String originalQuery = (String) externalContext.getRequestMap().get(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_QUERY_STRING);

            if (originalQuery != null) {
                originalURL += "?" + originalQuery;
            }
        }
    }

    public void login() throws IOException {

        HttpServletRequest request = WebContext.getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(username, password);

            if (originalURL != null) {
                WebContext.redirect(originalURL);
            } else {
                WebContext.redirect("/index.xhtml");
            }

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            WebContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Incorrect username or password!"));
        }
    }

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

I have put logging onto trace, the output after the submit button click is below:

```
2014-02-02 13:35:01,881 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Conversation] (default task-6) WELD-000327: Resuming conversation with id null
2014-02-02 13:35:01,882 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) servletPath /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,882 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) pathInfo null
2014-02-02 13:35:01,882 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) URL pattern of the FacesServlet executing the current request .xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,882 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) execute(com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@115359ad)
2014-02-02 13:35:01,883 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) Entering RestoreViewPhase
2014-02-02 13:35:01,883 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) New request: creating a view for /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,883 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) URL pattern of the FacesServlet executing the current request .xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,883 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) URL pattern of the FacesServlet executing the current request .xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,883 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.ViewRoot'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,884 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created new view for /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,884 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Locale for this view as determined by calculateLocale en_US
2014-02-02 13:35:01,884 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) RenderKitId for this view as determined by calculateRenderKitId HTML_BASIC
2014-02-02 13:35:01,884 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.factory] (default task-6) Resource-Url from external context: file:/opt/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp95c150145d0990a0/content-200a83a1e489dda9/login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,885 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) Exiting RestoreViewPhase
2014-02-02 13:35:01,885 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (default task-6)  [TIMING] - [2ms] : Execution time for phase (including any PhaseListeners) -> RESTORE_VIEW 1
2014-02-02 13:35:01,885 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) render(com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@115359ad)
2014-02-02 13:35:01,885 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) Entering RenderResponsePhase
2014-02-02 13:35:01,885 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) About to render view /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,885 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Building View: /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,885 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.factory] (default task-6) Resource-Url from external context: file:/opt/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/temp95c150145d0990a0/content-200a83a1e489dda9/login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,886 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.Output'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,886 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @5,9 <h:head> Component[2030916047_790d51c2] Created: javax.faces.component.UIOutput
2014-02-02 13:35:01,887 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.OutputBody'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,887 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @9,9 <h:body> Component[2030916047_790d51e8] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlBody
2014-02-02 13:35:01,887 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlForm'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,887 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @14,22 <h:form> Component[2030916047_790d518e] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm
2014-02-02 13:35:01,888 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlMessages'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,888 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @15,36 <h:messages> Component[2030916047_790d5194] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessages
2014-02-02 13:35:01,888 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlOutputLabel'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,888 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @16,52 <h:outputLabel> Component[2030916047_790d51a7] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel
2014-02-02 13:35:01,889 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlInputText'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,889 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @17,73 <h:inputText> Component[2030916047_790d51ba] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputText
2014-02-02 13:35:01,889 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) created validator of type 'javax.faces.Bean'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,889 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlMessage'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,889 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @18,31 <h:message> Component[2030916047_790d514d] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessage
2014-02-02 13:35:01,890 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlOutputLabel'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,890 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @20,81 <h:outputLabel> Component[2030916047_790d5140] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLabel
2014-02-02 13:35:01,890 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlInputSecret'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,891 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @21,75 <h:inputSecret> Component[2030916047_790d5153] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlInputSecret
2014-02-02 13:35:01,891 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) created validator of type 'javax.faces.Bean'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,891 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlMessage'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,891 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @22,31 <h:message> Component[2030916047_790d5166] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlMessage
2014-02-02 13:35:01,891 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlCommandButton'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,891 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.tag.component] (default task-6) /login.xhtml @24,92 <h:commandButton> Component[2030916047_790d5179] Created: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton
2014-02-02 13:35:01,892 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Rendering View: /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,894 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) URL pattern of the FacesServlet executing the current request .xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,894 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) URL pattern of the FacesServlet executing the current request .xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,895 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) component.getValue() returned Username
2014-02-02 13:35:01,895 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) Value to be rendered Username
2014-02-02 13:35:01,895 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) component.getValue() returned null
2014-02-02 13:35:01,895 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) Value to be rendered null
2014-02-02 13:35:01,895 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) component.getValue() returned Password
2014-02-02 13:35:01,895 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) Value to be rendered Password
2014-02-02 13:35:01,896 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) component.getValue() returned null
2014-02-02 13:35:01,896 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-6) Value to be rendered null
2014-02-02 13:35:01,896 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Begin writing marker for viewId /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,896 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) End writing marker for viewId /login.xhtml
2014-02-02 13:35:01,896 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Created component with component type of 'javax.faces.HtmlMessages'
2014-02-02 13:35:01,897 FINE  [javax.faces.component] (default task-6) No renderer-type for component j_id1
2014-02-02 13:35:01,897 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-6) Exiting RenderResponsePhase
2014-02-02 13:35:01,897 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (default task-6)  [TIMING] - [12ms] : Execution time for phase (including any PhaseListeners) -> RENDER_RESPONSE 6
2014-02-02 13:35:01,898 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-6) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
2014-02-02 13:35:11,597 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.client.txn] (Periodic Recovery) Send recover request for transaction origin node identifier 1 to EJB receiver with node name localhost
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I have now spent many hours trying to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Are the properties getter/setter methods implemented?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes they are implemented. I have updated the code snippet to include them.

Comment: It works perfectly for me replacing the `@Named` annotation by `@ManagedBean` (I don't have a CDI environment), removing the `actionListener` property from the button (you should only use `action`) and also removing the whole logic from the methods. Give it a try. BTW I'm with Mojarra JSF 2.1.26.

Comment: What JSF version are you using?  What CDI version?

Comment: Im using JSF2.2 and CDI1.1. Basically all Java EE7 API. And Mojarra 2.2.4

Comment: OK, I have found the problem. It is my set up in the web.xml. I have commented out all security-constraint and login-config info and it now calls the backing bean method correctly

Comment: You could post your solution as answer and mark the question as answered.

BTW: if you have further problems when trying to invoke an action-method you could take a look at this excellent post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my config in the web.xml was causing errors and preventing the beans method from being invoked.

I removed the following from my web.xml and the backing bean method was called:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>mysqldomain</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/index.xhtml?error=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```